# enviar el valor de seleccionado de opcion de la vista al controlador MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc

cuando presiona cualquiero de estas dos pestañas

```
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Saldos">Saldos</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#resumen">Resumen</a></li></ul>
```

quiero que me mande al controlador estos valores:

## Saldos     = 1

## resumen    = 2

en la vista tambien tengo la fecha, que funciona con toda normalidad

Vista:

```
@model PROYECT.Controllers.ModelParametros

<div class="modal-header">
    <h2 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i> Reportes </h2><br />
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Saldos">Saldos</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#resumen">Resumen</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ResumenFechaInicio, "Fecha Inicio  : ")
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ResumenFechaInicio, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "width200" } })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ResumenFechaInicio)
    </div>
</div>
```

Mi modelo donde declaro mis parametros:

```
public class ModelParametros
{
public int TipoReporte { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese una Fecha Valida")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime FechaInicio { get; set; }
}
```

en Model Parametros llega FechaInicio = `07/07/2107` y en el tipo de reposte quiero que llegue TipoReporte = `1` o TipoReporte = `2`
mi controlador:

```
public ActionResult Imprimir(ModelParametros parametros)
        {
        
        }
```

Comment: Fernandez, puedes aclarar la idea de tu pregunta? Es confusa.

Comment: ahora que tal, edite la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Si estoy entendiendo bien lo que buscas, me imagino una solución usando jquery:

Se necesitaría poner un elemento html hidden, y manipularlo según seleccionen el tab de acuerdo a otro elemento hidden dentro de cada tab:

```
@model PROYECT.Controllers.ModelParametros

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h2 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i> Reportes </h2><br />
        @Html.Hidden("TipoReporte", "1")
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="TipoReporteTab active"><input type="hidden" class="TipoReporteTab" value="1" /><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Saldos">Saldos</a></li>
            <li class="TipoReporteTab"><input type="hidden" class="TipoReporteTab" value="2" /><a data-toggle="tab" href="#resumen">Resumen</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ResumenFechaInicio, "Fecha Inicio  : ")
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ResumenFechaInicio, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "width200" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ResumenFechaInicio)
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </div>
}

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('.TipoReporteTab').on('click', function () {
                $('#TipoReporte').val($(this).find(".TipoReporteTab").val());
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```